# T-SQL: Split Data from one column into two columns based on the column value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a single temp table `[#Procedures]` with data like this:

```
PatientID   OrderDate     ProcedureCode
---------------------------------------
1           5/1/2023      111
1           5/1/2023      222
1           5/1/2023      D111
2           5/1/2023      D111
2           5/1/2023      D112
3           5/1/2023      111
3           5/1/2023      222
4           5/1/2023      D111
4           5/1/2023      D112
4           5/1/2023      222
```

I want to show it like this:

```
PatientID   MedOrderDate  MedProcedure   DenOrderDate.  DenProcedure
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1           5/1/2023          111        5/1/2023          D111
1           5/1/2023          222        5/1/2023
2           5/1/2023                     5/1/2023          D111
2           5/1/2023                     5/1/2023          D112
3           5/1/2023          111        5/1/2023    
3           5/1/2023          222        5/1/2023
4           5/1/2023          222        5/1/2023          D111
4           5/1/2023                     5/1/2023          D112
```

I have tried the following:

1. Created a temp table `[#PatientIDs]` with distinct `PatientID`s to ensure I capture all `PatientID`s.
2. Started a query using `#PatientIDs` as the first table in the select list and then left-joining to `#Procedures` twice - once for Medical Procedures and once for Dental Procedures.

This is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    p.PatientID, pr.OrderDate AS MedicalOrderDate, 
    pr.ProcedureCode AS MedicalProcedure,       
    d.ProcedureCode AS DentalProcedure, 
    d.OrderDate AS DentalOrderDate
FROM
    #PatientIDs p
LEFT JOIN
    #Procedures pr ON pr.PatientId = p.PatientID 
                   AND ProcedureCode NOT LIKE 'D%'
LEFT JOIN
    #Procedures d ON d.PatientId = p.PatientID 
                  AND ProcedureCode LIKE 'D%'
```

The problem is that this returns wrong data. For example, `PatientID = 1` shows `D111` twice - once for each of the Medical Procedures.

I believe there must be a way that this can be done in a single query, but I don't know how.

I'd appreciate any help or pointers I can get.

Thanks!

Comment: You're asking to *pivot* the data - search for that it's very common.

Comment: What would you expect if something happened on a different date? Perhaps you could expand your sample data and expected results to cover that possibility, as well as an explanation of the algorithm you have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with window functions and conditional aggregation. Assuming that you have a column to order the records, say `pk`:

```
select patientID,
    max(case when procedureCode not like 'D%' then orderDate     end) medOrderDate,
    max(case when procedureCode not like 'D%' then procedureCode end) medProcedure,
    max(case when procedureCode     like 'D%' then orderDate     end) denOrderDate,
    max(case when procedureCode     like 'D%' then procedureCode end) denProcedure
from (    
    select p.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by patientID, case when procedureCode like 'D%' then 0 else 1 end
            order by pk
        ) rn
    from #procedures p
) p
group by patientID, rn
order by patientID, rn
```

| patientID | medOrderDate | medProcedure | denOrderDate | denProcedure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-05-01 | 111 | 2023-05-01 | D111 |
| 1 | 2023-05-01 | 222 | *null* | *null* |
| 2 | *null* | *null* | 2023-05-01 | D111 |
| 2 | *null* | *null* | 2023-05-01 | D112 |
| 3 | 2023-05-01 | 111 | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | 2023-05-01 | 222 | *null* | *null* |
| 4 | 2023-05-01 | 222 | 2023-05-01 | D111 |
| 4 | *null* | *null* | 2023-05-01 | D112 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HaoZfhKa)